# Empty Buffer when read char pointer data using node-ffi

Tags: node-ffi

The DLL file was developed in Delphi. The Function was described as bellow:

> Function name: GetMsg
>
> Function description: It is used to get error
>   info.
>
> Function prototype: procedure GetMsg(ret: Integer; var Msg:
>   PChar); stdcall;
>
> Parameter description: ret: It indicates error code. Msg: It is used
>   to output the corresponding error info.
>
> Firstly, you need to allocate
>   memory. The memory is greater than or equal to 255.

According to the description, I know `Msg` parameter is a pointer, then I use node-ffi to invoke the `GetMsg` procedure as bellow:

```js
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var TheLib = ffi.Library('TheLib.dll', {
  GetMsg: ['void', ['int', ref.types.CString]]
});
const outNameBuffer = Buffer.alloc(255);
TheLib.GetMsg(-25, outNameBuffer);
console.log(outNameBuffer, ref.readCString(outNameBuffer));
```

I always get this response:
[image: result of the code]

Note that, I i use `ctypes` in Python, I could get a Chinese message corresponding to the value `-25`.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had about the same problem, try my solution:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var ArrayType = require('ref-array');
var charPtrArray = ArrayType('char *', 64);
var charPtrArrayPtr = ref.refType(charPtrArray);

var TheLib = ffi.Library('TheLib.dll', {
  GetMsg: ['void', ['int', charPtrArrayPtr]
});

console.log(charPtrArrayPtr);
```

Comment: Thank you @sape639, but that code did not work in my case. I switched to use Python and everything got easier :D